# Spring JPA Data: Custom Generic Repositories and Services: UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, generic-programming

I'm working on a restful service with a lot of entities. If we consider two groups of *father resources* and *child resources*, both group members has same implementation for CRUD operations in their group scope

So, there is not only one generic class for each layer. Here's my Code:

REPOSITORIES:

base repository which have methods used by all entities:

```
@Repository
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

*father resources* repository

```
@Repository
public interface EntityGenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericRepository<T, ID> {
    T findByName(String name);
}
```

and *child resources* repository

```
@Repository
public interface NestedEntityGenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericRepository<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findByFatherId(ID fatherId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

SERVICES:

for base:

```
public interface GenericService<T,ID extends Serializable> {
    Page<T> findAll(int page, int size);

    T findById(ID id);
}
```

for father:

```
public interface EntityGenericService<T, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericService<T, ID> {
    T findByName(String name);

    T save(T t);

    void update(ID id, T t);

    void softDelete(ID id);
}
```

and for child:

```
public interface NestedEntityGenericService<T, ID extends Serializable> {
    Page<T> findBySensorId(ID fatherId, int page, int size);

    T save(ID fatherId, T t);

    void update(ID fatherId, ID id, T t);

    void softDelete(ID fatherId, ID id);
}
```

SERVICE IMPLEMENTATIONS:

base:

```
@Service
public class GenericServiceImpl<T,ID extends Serializable>
        implements GenericService<T,ID> { //codes }
```

for father:

```
@Service
public class EntityGenericServiceImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends GenericServiceImpl<T, ID>
        implements EntityGenericService<T, ID> {//codes}
```

and for child:

```
@Service
public class NestedEntityGenericServiceImpl<T, U, ID extends Serializable>
        extends EntityGenericServiceImpl<T, ID>
        implements NestedEntityGenericService<T, ID> {//codes}
```

When I run it, it just throws `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. The whole message:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating 
bean with name 'entityGenericServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
field 'genericRepository': Error creating bean with name 'nestedEntityGenericRepository': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'nestedEntityGenericRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
```

Searched a lot but found nothing that fix this issue. Any Help is appreciated

Regards

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51694938/5380322

Comment: @Cepr0 thanks for that. but if I want to do that, it wont satisfy the purpose of generics cause i would still have duplicate methods which are going to do the same job and of course, I can't use my custom methods defined in repository

Comment: how do you create a concrete implementation of your own generic repositories?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I just create an object of it in service layer

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I fixed it. for using spring repositories, interfaces must be defined concrete in the last level.

Comment: Great. Can you post this as the answer, please. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this Problem by creating concrete repositories for each entity.
I was trying to reduce number of classes. So I defined 3 generic repositories to do the job of all other repositories defined to serve all entities. But I understood it's impossible and concrete repositories must be defined in last level of custom repository for interaction with service layer.

The reason is reflection. Spring uses reflection to do all the behind the curtain and it must know for which entity it must use provider (Hibernate)

It's necessary to note that if you want to create generic service layer, it must have concrete implementation in its last level as well. because concrete repositories must be declared somewhere